# Drupal 9 after installation, example site launches in browser, but keeps loading

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I installed drupal in a directory with composer, with the demo site:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project drupal1 --stability dev --no-interaction

cd drupal1 && php -d memory_limit=256M web/core/scripts/drupal quick-start demo_umami
```

the site appears on the screen, but it keeps loading, forever.
Any ideas of what is going on wrong?

Also, clicking on the menu items does not go to another page. Only the JavaScript menus of the administrator change, but the site is not unresponsive, I can scroll up or down.

It can stop loading and can go to another page.